# Newly opened applications open in background

Tags: windows, 13.04, focus, background-process

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 on an ASUS X201EP.

Often, when I launch a program (usually chromium or the file manager) it will open in the background, behind the currently opened window. This is very annoying! For example, I might download a file in chromium, then from within the browser, click "show in folder." This will open the file manager BEHIND the browser window, meaning I have to go click on the "files" icon on the left side of the screen to see my downloaded file.

It's not a huge deal, but it's one of those little annoyances that bugs me throughout the day. Has anyone ever had this problem? I've tried googling "app opens in background," and other similar searches, but I haven't been able to find anything. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See this (which I think this answer is a duplicate of): http://askubuntu.com/questions/162757/why-some-windows-in-ubuntu-12-04-opens-in-background

Comment: The solution in that link worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answered by MiJyn, in this link:
[Disable new windows auto opening in background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162757/why-some-windows-in-ubuntu-12-04-opens-in-background)

Here is the solution posted there, by MattBAustinTX

- get `compizconfig-settings-manager`
- Press `Alt+F2` and type `ccsm`
- select the category "General"
- click on "General Options"
- Select the "Focus and Raise Behaviour" tab
- Check "Auto-raise" and set "Focus Prevention" level to Off

That fixed things up for me. Hope it does for you as well.